# Calorimeter and bond energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics

Why does 1,3-Butadiene has different standard heat of formation value calculated from calorimeter than the one calculated from bond energies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the resonance. buta-1,3-diene is resonance stabilized. The Heat of combustion actually will be less than calculated theoretically because some of energy released will be used to destabilize the molecule.